# Users and service using database at same time

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my app, user interactions open and close the SQLite Database. No problem with that.

But, weekly, a service is launched to update the database, it fetches data via network (everything's ok) and then the service does queries to update the database.
If users are using the app while the database is updated, then some operations done by users may try to open or close the database while it is doing some work and then an error is raised:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to close due to unfinalised statements
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbclose(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.onAllReferencesReleased(SQLiteDatabase.java:325)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.close(SQLiteDatabase.java:1025)
```

Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: You could always prompt the user to initiate the update and then disable the app while update is in progress.

Comment: Sure but I would like the update to do in background. So that if the user decide to use the app in a place where he does not have an internet access, the database is already updated...

Comment: Then your app should check to see if database update is in progress at startup.

Comment: have you tried using synchronized with the data access functions ?